# How to get only recurring events from google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am working on developing integration with Google Calendar using Rest APIs. I want to know if there is any way to pull only recurring events from a Google Calendar.

I am using this API but not able to work it out so far - https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events

Comment: doesn't the event response include recurrence?

Comment: it is there, but we want to fetch directly from server. If we rely on event response, it may occur that we may have to traverse across multiple pages, and filter out only recurring events to build a single page.